# What's the maximum theoretical data transfer throughput of NTFS?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Recently I was at a local user group meeting where the presenter noted that the maximum throughput of the NTFS IO stack was 1 GBps. He substantiated his claim by simultaneously copying two large files from the same logical volume to different logical volumes (i.e. [a] is the source, [b] is destination 1 and [c] is destination 2) and noting the transfer rates hovering around 500 MBps. He repeated this test a few times and noted that the underlying storage subsystem was flash (to make sure we didn't suspect slow storage).

I've been trying to verify this assertion but cannot find anything documented. I suspect that I'm searching for the wrong search terms ("1GBps NTFS throughput", "NTFS throughput maximum"). I'm interested in whether or not the IO stack is actually limited to 1GBps throughput.

EDIT

To clarify: I do not believe the presenter intended to imply that NTFS was *intentionally* limited (and I'm sorry if I implied that as well). I think it *was* implied that it was a function of the design of the filesystem.

Comment: 1GB/s is pretty fast even for flash drive(s)

Comment: Deleted my answer because I'm almost sure I saw Gbps in your question, but I think you meant GB/s, and either way you'll get lots of other good answers.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins 1 GB/s != 1 Gbps

Comment: I agree, but his question says "... the maximum throughput of the NTFS IO stack was 1 GBps", as far as I know B=bytes and b=bits

Comment: Simple experiment -- copy the file across RAM disks? Not difficult to get 16 * 2 = 32GB of RAM these days.

Comment: The copy function in windows explorer is slow and sends a lot of overhead data back and forth. You can demonstrate that using FTP is much faster for example. That is not NTFS though.

Comment: JamesRyan - using FTP as the transfer mechanism does not suddenly change the filesystem. Don't confuse SMB with NTFS.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins - 1GB/s is not fast enough when you're copying virtual machine images around.

Comment: @Matt that is a judgement call. Many disk subsystems can't handle 1GB/s, especially if the IO is non-sequential. In my largest ESX cluster we do hit 2GB/s pretty regularly but even the busiest hosts very rarely spike above 4GB/s. That's with 2 TB of SSD cache and 400 spindles. Not saying you won't bottleneck on a gig link but it's a lot more common for the problem to be on your storage device.

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins - very true... my comment was an off the cuff one.  I should have said that fast is never quite fast enough.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Even assuming you meant `GBps` and not `Gbps`...

I am unaware of any filesystem that has an actual `throughput limit`.  Filesystems are simply structures around how to store and retrieve files.  They use metadata, structure, naming conventions, security conventions, etc. but the actual throughput limitations are defined by the underlying hardware itself (typically a combination of lots of hardware involved).

Comparing different filesystems and how they **affect** performance of the underlying hardware can be done, but again that isn't a limitation directly imposed by the filesystem but more of a "variable" in the overall performance of the system.

Choosing to deploy one filesystem over another is typically related to what the underlying OS is, what the server/application is going to be, what the underlying hardware is, and *soft* factors such as the admin's areas of expertise and familiarity.

==================================================================================

### **TECHNICAL RESOURCES AND CITATIONS**

---

**[Optimizing NTFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc767961.aspx)**

> NTFS Performance Factors
>
> You determine many of the factors that affect an NTFS volumes'
>   performance. You choose important elements such as an NTFS volume's
>   type (e.g., SCSI, or IDE), speed (e.g., the disks' rpm speed), and the
>   number of disks the volume contains. In addition to these important
>   components, the following factors significantly influence an NTFS
>   volume's performance:
>
> - The cluster and allocation unit size
> - The location and fragmentation level of frequently accessed files, such as the Master File Table (MFT), directories, special files
>     containing NTFS metadata, the paging file, and commonly used user data
>     files
> - Whether you create the NTFS volume from scratch or convert it from an existing FAT volume
> - Whether the volume uses NTFS compression
> - Whether you disable unnecessary NTFS behaviors
>
> Using faster disks and more drives in multidisk volumes is an obvious
>   way to improve performance. The other performance improvement methods
>   are more obscure and relate to the details of an NTFS volume's
>   configuration.

---

**[Scalability and Performance in Modern File Systems](http://linux-xfs.sgi.com/projects/xfs/papers/xfs_white/xfs_white_paper.html)**

> Unfortunately, it is impossible to do direct performance comparisons
>   of the file systems under discussion since they are not all available
>   on the same platform. Further, since available data is necessarily
>   from differing hardware platforms, **it is difficult to distinguish the
>   performance characteristics of the file system from that of the
>   hardware platform on which it is running.**

---

[NTFS Optimization](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_optimization.htm)

[New white paper providing guidance for sizing NTFS volumes](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2011/02/22/new-white-paper-providing-guidance-for-sizing-ntfs-volumes.aspx)

[What's new in NTFS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383236%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[Configuring NTFS file system for performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/46881/configuring-ntfs-file-system-for-performance)

https://superuser.com/questions/411720/how-does-ntfs-compression-affect-performance

[Best practices for NTFS compression in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251186)

Comment: well, he said "gigaBYTES per second" so that's what I was working with.

Comment: Even still, I could give a symposium with only 802.11g connected on all devices and swear the throughput limit of NTFS was <54Mbps by demonstrating over and over a copy between the devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't believe that he was suggesting that NTFS had an intentional limit, but that somehow the design was sufficiently old enough that it never really considered rates this high. So yes, I think it's more of a conversation about how filesystems affect performance of underlying hardware. Also, the point you made is well-taken, and I would have to take his word for the fact that he was RDC'd to his server with the storage actually attached in a production-simulated environment.

Comment: Could be, but saying "NTFS has a hard limit" vs. "NTFS is _slower_ than ext4 on <x> hardware" is a big difference.  He may have mispoke, you might have misinterpreted, regardless...there you go.

Comment: Again, NTFS the filesystem won't have any such limitation, but a given NTFS driver might.

Comment: Agree @mfinni ..

Comment: Don't think of it as a limit but an logical overhead.  That also includes the driver as a "set" limit would have to be a definition value defined in the code of the driver.  However I understand you thought process <- (@mfinni)...   hard limits are defined in throughput on disk ability to process Read/Write IO and also the technical limitations of the transport medium.

Comment: Nice adds, @TheCleaner

Answer (score 11):

I very much doubt there is a data transfer bottleneck related to a *filesystem*, because *filesystems* don't dictate *implementation details* that would hard-limit *performance*. A given *driver* for a filesystem on a particular config of hardware will have bottlenecks of course.

Comment: I didn't think it was intentionally limited, but thought that, perhaps, it was a limitation of the design

Comment: Thanks for the focus down from "filesystem" to "driver."

Comment: You can't increase the speed of a book - you can increase the speed of the reader and things the reader depends on.

Comment: Limits and bottle necks are two different things...    as a File System can cause overhead it is theoretically possible to create a bottle-neck but will not define a hard set limit which I believe was the intent meant in this post.

Answer (score 7):

I would be *very* surprised if this was true. Let's look at everything that can slow down a filesystem:

- The physical media (disk, ssd)
- Connection to this media (sas, sata, fcal)
- Fragmentation
- Bad locking algorithms or other code issues
- CPU and memory speed

The most common limiting factor is your physical media. Rotating rust is *SLOW*. Take for instance [this really new disk](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/10318310) which has a maximum speed of 6 Gbps (that's Gbps, not GBps!). Of course using a raid 1 setup will speed this up. Of course you'll never achieve this, as seeks kill your performance. So let's use [an SSD](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product.aspx?sku=10447652&pagemode=ca) you say? Oh look at that, 6Gb again.

Then there's the connection: sas (the fastest local storage) goes up to 6 Gbps, FC goes up to 16Gbps though.

Are you sure your demo was using such high end, state of the art, hardware?

If you are: interesting! You may have hit case 3 and your filesystem needs some optimizing. Or more likely your drivers and application are eating up your CPU (5). If neither of those are though, you may have hit upon an actual performance issue in NTFS, please report it to microsoft.

And even then: this is not an artificial limit, put in place to make your life more miserable. Filesystems don't intentionally limit transfer speeds, but are limited by whatever your hardware can give you.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a maximum.  But I know it's more than 1 GB/s because the people at Samsung did 2121.29 MB/s read and 2000.195 MB/s write with their 2009 rig with 24 SSD drives  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96dWOEa4Djs

They think they hit that limit because this was the combined total hardware bandwidth of the controller cards the SSDs were plugged in to.

Also this page http://blog.laptopmag.com/faster-than-an-ssd-how-to-turn-extra-memory-into-a-ram-disk shows a RAM disk formatted with NTFS getting 5 to 7 GB/s. Try it yourself with one of the RAMdisk titles listed on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to theorize whether or not there's a 1 GBps limit to NTFS--[modern SSDs already surpass this](http://www.thessdreview.com/our-reviews/kingspec-multicore-1tb-driverless-pci-express-ssd-review-2-5gbs-simple-plug-play-installation/).  The test bench is a Windows desktop.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The only logical way to compare filesystem limits would be to do so across systems where the constant was the filesystem and the variables were the other factors such as devices, connections, etc.  Using one system to compare transfer speeds over several iterations prove only that the particular system was limited, not that the filesystem was limited.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built - in throughput limit in NTFS. The only constraint on speed is the performance characteristics of the underlying hardware.

Comment: I didn't think it was intentionally limited, but thought that, perhaps, it was a limitation of the design.

Comment: @swasheck I don't think it's possible to design a filesystem that won't transfer data twice as fast if you've got a processor twice as fast and can read the disk twice as fast and can seek twice as fast. Even the most inefficient possible design can be made faster by making everything it uses faster.